# Referencing data held in an Access Database with Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

My project is a small *Access* database with two tables. The first table is *"EMPLOYEES"* and the second table is *"TOOLS"*. The database keeps track of what specific tools each employee has in his/her possession. My Visual Basic form adds and deletes employees from the database via the dataset. 
What I would like to do is set a variable to hold the Employees full name taken from two different fields. (The "FirstName" field and the "LastName" field)
How do I reference (or get the value of) the *"FIRST_NAME"* and *"LAST_NAME"* data stored in the *"EMPLOYEE"* table so that I can set my Visual Basic string Variable with those two values.
Is this a job for SQL?

Something like this:

```
     For i As int32 = 0 To myDATABASE.EMPLOYEES.column.Length

        Dim fullName As String = _
                         myDATABASE.EMPLOYEES.row(i).FIRST_NAME _
                         & " " & _
                         MyDATABASE.EMPLOYEES.row(i).LAST_NAME

        mylistBox.add("The full name is: " & fullName)

     Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate the names in sql as Wayne G. Dunn suggests or you can also do it in vb like this:

```
    For i As Int32 = 0 To MyDATABASE.Tables("EMPLOYEES").Rows.Count - 1
        Dim fullName As String = _
                       MyDATABASE.Tables("EMPLOYEES").Rows(i).Item("FIRST_NAME").ToString() _
                         & " " & _
                         MyDATABASE.Tables("EMPLOYEES").Rows(i).Item("LAST_NAME").ToString()

        mylistBox.add("The full name is: " & fullName)
    Next
```

For something as simple as putting two strings together it's really a matter of personal preference and it's good to know both ways.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for (I think) but I am getting a Null reference exception when I try to use the dataset like this:   For i As Int32 = 0 DB_ToolsDataSet.Tables("EMPLOYEES").Rows.Count - 1    For i As Int32 = 0 To MyDATABASE.Tables("EMPLOYEES").Rows.Count - 1

Comment: I'm sorry. I did not edit the code correctly to fit my program. The table was named ("tbl_Employees") and I had left it ("EMPLOYEES"). That is what was causing the error. Once I corrected my mistake it worked perfect for what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to populate a listbox with names, then you can set the recordsource to something like:

> Select [First_Name] & " " & [Last_Name] as FullName from Employees